# Getting errors when installing pymc on Linux

Tags: linux, python-2.7, pymc

When I try to install  `pymc` using `easy_install pymc`

I am getting following errors

```
warning: no files found matching 'README.txt'
warning: no files found matching 'INSTALL.txt'
warning: no files found matching 'docs/UserGuide.pdf'
Could not locate executable gfortran
Could not locate executable f95
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifc
Could not locate executable lf95
Could not locate executable pgfortran
Could not locate executable f90
Could not locate executable f77
Could not locate executable fort
Could not locate executable efort
Could not locate executable efc
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable g95
Could not locate executable pathf95
don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
warning: build_ext: f77_compiler=None is not available.
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04
How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to install the fortran compiler?
You also might get better results doing a "sudo pip install pymc"